# How to print specific content of a command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to list a lot of information from batch file in a txt file.

But, some commands give a "prefix" and only after, give the real information.

I need to print only the information, below have a wmic command where give a prefix before.

`wmic /OUTPUT:C:\CPU.txt cpu get name`

the output:

**Name

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz**

I need only the second line, without the "Name", how I can do this?

Comment: Type `wmic /format /?`.

Answer (score 2):

```
wmic cpu get name|find /v /i "name" > "C:\CPU.txt"
```